# What is the hypothesis space of decision tree learning?

Tags: decision-trees

Could you please explain what the hypothesis space for decision tree learning look like?

And what is the cardinality of this space?

Answer (score 2):

As per Tom Mitchell's,

".....For example, consider the space of
hypotheses that could in principle be output by the above checkers learner. This
**hypothesis space consists of all evaluation functions that can be represented by
some choice of values for the weights** wo through w6. **The learner's task is thus to
search through this vast space to locate the hypothesis that is most consistent with
the available training examples**....."

Hence , Basically all possible combination of distinct trees makes the hypothesis space.

Lets say if you have chosen to represent your function to be a linear line then all possible linear lines which go through the data (given input, output) makes up your hypothesis space.

Each tree= Single hypothesis , that says this tree shall best fit my data and predict the correct results

therefore combination of all such possible tress= hypothesis space.

Here is the snippet of PPT from [lecture](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~russell/classes/cs194/f11/lectures/CS194%20Fall%202011%20Lecture%2008.pdf)

[image]